# PHP RSA syntax highlighting

Tags: php

Why is one of the parameter white while others are yellow?[image]

Comment: function is misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

You should change **functioun** with **function** on line 12.

Comment: so simple... no idea how i could missed that, thanks

Comment: @user1269348 You might want to use a PHP language server to help you find trivial errors such as these.